# Даны две переменные со словарем и словарем с вложенным списком. Как написать функцию в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, циклы

Есть исходная структура с хранимыми данными:

```
documents = [
{'type': 'passport', 'number': '2207 876234', 'name': 'Василий Гупкин'},
{'type': 'invoice', 'number': '11-2', 'name': 'Геннадий Покемонов'},
{'type': 'insurance', 'number': '10006', 'name': 'Аристарх Павлов'}
]

directories = {
'1': ['2207 876234', '11-2'],
'2': ['10006'],
'3': []
}
```

Задача:
Пользователь по команде “l” может увидеть полную информацию по всем документам
Пример работы:

Введите команду:
l
Результат:

```
№: 2207 876234, тип: passport, владелец: Василий Гупкин, полка хранения: 1
№: 11-2, тип: invoice, владелец: Геннадий Покемонов, полка хранения: 1
№: 10006, тип: insurance, владелец: Аристарх Павлов, полка хранения: 2
```

На данный момент реализовал только часть задания:

```
def l():
    for c in documents:
        type = c['type']
        number = c['number']
        name = c['name']
        print('№: {1}, тип: {0}, владелец: {2}'.format(type, number, name))
        
    l()
```

результат

```
№: 2207 876234, тип: passport, владелец: Василий Гупкин
№: 11-2, тип: invoice, владелец: Геннадий Покемонов
№: 10006, тип: insurance, владелец: Аристарх Павлов
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну во первых не стоит называть переменную `type`.
Можно написать небольшую функцию `get_key` для получения ключа по значению.

```
documents = [
{'type': 'passport', 'number': '2207 876234', 'name': 'Василий Гупкин'},
{'type': 'invoice', 'number': '11-2', 'name': 'Геннадий Покемонов'},
{'type': 'insurance', 'number': '10006', 'name': 'Аристарх Павлов'}
]

directories = {
'1': ['2207 876234', '11-2'],
'2': ['10006'],
'3': []
}

def get_key(d, value):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if value in v:
            return k

def l():
    for c in documents:
        doc_type = c['type']
        number = c['number']
        name = c['name']
        print('№: {1}, тип: {0}, владелец: {2} полка{3}'.format(doc_type, number, name, get_key(directories,number)))
        
l()
```